# How do I add a regular expression to a mapping command in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to map `:b<buffer_number><cr>` to `<leader>b<buffer_number>`. I have:

```
nmap <leader>b :b
```

which is not enough, because I still have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I also tried:

```
nmap <leader>b :execute 'b' (v:count) <cr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `[count]`, you can define:

```
nnoremap <leader>b :<C-u>execute 'b' v:count<cr>
```

With this, you have to *prepend* the count, e.g. `4<Leader>b`, that's also consistent with other Vim commands. The `<C-u>` removes the automatically added range.

The problem with a trailing count is determining how many digits to query; you then either need to specify all digits (i.e. `03` instead of `3`), query another key to end the mapping, or wait for a timeout.

Here's a simplistic mapping that only queries a single digit:

```
nnoremap <leader>b :execute 'b' nr2char(getchar())<cr>
```

<sup>(PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There's already `[count]<C-^>` (or `[count]<C-6>` on some keyboards layouts):

```
2<C-^>
6<C-^>
```

and so on…